# iOS Firebase Cloud Firestore batch() .addDocument()

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Looking over the the firestore documentation on Batched write
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

But, it doesn't say anything about adding a document to a collection.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setData` method ([class reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/WriteBatch#setdata_fordocumentmergefields)) creates a document if not already existing, or (by default) overwrites the data on that reference path if it already exists.

```
// Create or overwrite data for document with ID "NYC"
let nycRef = db.collection("cities").document("NYC") 
batch.setData([:], forDocument: nycRef)

// Create a document with a random unique ID
let docRef = db.collection("places").document() 
batch.setData([:], forDocument: docRef)
```